# populate a table with thymeleaf with very large registers or data

Tags: java, html, spring, populate, thymeleaf

hi i am working in a spring mvc project using thymeleaf and i have a method that executes a very complex query that takes `7 seconds` to return 1500 rows, i have to populate a table with that data using thymeleaf, but its taking too much time populating the table, it takes 1 min to populate the table and show the web page, so it takes 1 min loading the page, is there a way to populate a table when you have a lot of data without taking too much time??

i used to think that it was taking too much time loading was because my method returns a list Objects and i need to cast that list of objects to my proper POJO object so i have to loop the list and cast each object,

but its not that because i try the following tests

1) i try printing the list objects in a simple TextArea without the casting method and it printed me all the Objects, it took `9 secs` to show the web page but you need to take out the 7 seconds that took the query to bring the data

it printed like 1000 objects like this in my textArea:

[Ljava.lang.Object;@e9548,[Ljava.lang.Object;@e9548.....

2) i try printing the list in a simple TextArea with my method that cast each object to my POJO objects and it took  `10 secs` almost the same time that it took when i printed the raw object list without my cast method

it printed like 1000 objects like this in my textArea:  `com.abc.serviceClass.Person@252c46, com.abc.serviceClass.Person@252c46,  com.abc.serviceClass.Person@252c46, com.abc.serviceClass.Person@252c46.....`

3) this is why i think that the method that use thymeleaf to populate the table have the fault of the web page taking almost `1 min to load`, Becasue when i populate my table using this code

```
<table>
    <tbody>
          <tr th:each="nodeInfo : ${listOfPojos}">

                                            <td th:text="${nodeInfo.name}"></td>

                                            <td th:text="${nodeInfo.lastName}"></td>
        </tr>  



     </tbody>
</table>
```

that `th:each` that have to iteare the 1500 registers that are in my listOfPojos and print the value i believe is why is taking too much time it takes more than 1 min to show my web page when i put that code, thats why i wanted to ask if its another way to populate my table using that list of 1500 pojos objects without taking that whole minute to show the page.

Comment: We have exactly the same problem a few days ago, but we finally decide to switch to AJAX calls, Thymleaf is not good at all when you use th:each, I hope they will make some better changes in the next relases. Our page now is loaded without populating this big list in the server side, all is happen in the client side

Comment: hi man can you help me or point to a tutorial or how do you did that, when you say on the clint side it means that you have a `javaScript` script in your html page that populate the table? if that is the case how do you get the list with all the pojos? in my case the `ListOfPersons` becasue i get that list from a controller like this:

`model.addAttribute("listOfPOJOs", myList_that_i_get_from_a_method);`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, keep in mind that displaying so many rows client-side is not recommended, even if current browsers are more and more performing.

Anyway, for your particular needs, [Dandelion-Datatables](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables) may help, especially its [server-side](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/features/ajax/server-side/index.html) features, if you (your client I mean) accept to page the results.

Under the hood, DataTables performs an AJAX call with some information, for example the number of rows to display, the starting element and the ending one. Of course you have to make available server-side some queries that read these parameters and perform the corresponding query.

A sample is available [here](https://github.com/dandelion/dandelion-samples/tree/master/datatables/datatables-thymeleaf-ajax), using your technology stack.

*Disclaimer required by StackOverflow, I'm the author of the Dandelion project.*

Comment: i have a doubt when you guys talk about server-side what part are you talking about? because i believe that theres no way to populate a table in the server side, what i do in the server side is get data from the database, put that data into a list and then return that list to the html page (and i understand that the html page is the client side), so how can you populate the table in the server side and then return a table???

Comment: Indeed, there's not way to populate a table in the server side, nor good reason too I think. By server-side processing, I mean "a method to let all the "heavy lifting" be done by a database engine on the server-side (they are after-all highly optimised for exactly this kind of thing), and then have that information drawn in the user's web-browser" (quoted from http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side). So the trick is to perform as few processing client-side as processing by returning an already filtered/paged list of rows.

Comment: mmmm so since i am not able to modify my query what should i do, i dont mind using javascript or ajax if that helps?.  but i have a doubt what should i need to modify?, the way i extract the data  ??, i dont mind waitng those 8 seconds that takes the query to run and the time i take to convert that data in a list of POJOs, my problem is with the 40 seconds that takes thymeleaf to do that loop  `<tr th:each="nodeInfo : ${listOfPojos}">`.. So what should i do with my list of pojos before passing it to my html page??